# Listen to websocket outside of my Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, websocket

My application is a VueJS frontend and a Laravel Backend API. I want to subscribe to Binance API WebSocket but I'm unsure how to do it.

Any ideas?
I'm talking about the high level design of it. I was not able to find a way to listen to a WebSocket from the backend in Laravel.

- FYI, I've already setup a websocket server and I'm sending events through it so my Vue JS Front end knows when the specific event happens, now I need to actually take the event from Binance WebSocket. It's important for me to listen to the websocket from the backend since that's where the action should happen.

For sure this has to run somewhere at the back in some kind of isolated env or ?

Comment: Have you received any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want, but...
e.g:

Method 1: Using Laravel Echo Server

Laravel Echo Server is a Node.js server that allows you to listen to WebSocket connections outside of your Laravel application. You can install Laravel Echo Server using the following command:

(https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)

npm install -g laravel-echo-server

After installing Laravel Echo Server, you can start it using the following command:

laravel-echo-server start

You can also configure Laravel Echo Server using the following command:

laravel-echo-server init

You can find more information about Laravel Echo Server here:

Method 2: Using Pusher

Pusher is a service that allows you to listen to WebSocket connections outside of your Laravel application. You can find more information about Pusher here:

https://pusher.com/

Method 3: Using Redis

Redis is a service that allows you to listen to WebSocket connections outside of your Laravel application. You can find more information about Redis here:

https://redis.io/

Method 4: Using Socket.io

Socket.io is a service that allows you to listen to WebSocket connections outside of your Laravel application. You can find more information about Socket.io here:

https://socket.io/

Did you want such an example?

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do is - Subscribe to WebSocket on Binance more specifically this one https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#payload-order-update and whenever there is a Order triggered - do updates in my backend.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue recently, I found a solution which is, you can use a package called vue-pusher, by using it you can easily listen to any event, the uses are like this:

first import the package and set the params

```
Vue.use(require('vue-pusher'), {
api_key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
options: {
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true,
}
});
```

then in the template use it like this:

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

this.$pusher.subscribe('YOUR_EVENT_NAME')
  this.$pusher.bind('your_variable', data => {
    
    let tempdata = JSON.stringify(data);
    let newdata = JSON.parse(tempdata);
    this.messages.push(newdata.message);
    console.log('wokring');
  })
```

I used it for live chat so i just push the new message in the messages array, here you can do your stuff.

Comment: But in my opinion this needs to happen in the backend.
Why ? Because I think there has to be at least one client opened in order for that event to be catched. I need to listen to this from the backend from the Laravel Application. The way that you described is listening for an event from the front end and then I need to call the Backend to do my stuff, but isn't there a way to actually do it derectly in the Backend ?

Comment: No that actually not the case, whats happening here is same, in my laravel application i am publishing the event from controller whenever a new message came, and in vue I am just listening to them, you can also do the same thing

Comment: But I already have a PHP code that can listen to it, I just don't know where to put it in the Laravel Application look  https://prnt.sc/WiPjuvLvNlOR

Comment: You can just make an api route and put that in the controller corresponding that route